# how to get opposite of number in C#?

Tags: c#, numbers, integer, flip, inverse

I'm not sure what the name is for the operation I am attempting, but I would like to "flip" the value of a number within a given range.

I have a C# program that receives a number that varies from any value from 1 to 1023.  How would I  "flip" the number so that if I receive 1023 then it would be 1, 750 would be 274, and 512 would still be 512 since its exactly half?

I was thinking of using some type of loop but I have never done anything like this.  My research came up with people wanting to, for example, turn 40 into 04, but that's not what I am looking for.

Comment: if it's 750, the answer should be 274, no?

Comment: "if its 750 the it would make it 250" - I don't think so !!!

Comment: sorry guys but i didn't do the math there, just a quick estimate geez.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If your input number is x then your answer is the expression `1024-x`

In general, if you have numbers in the range of 1 to max, then the answer would be `(max+1)-x`

Comment: Once, long ago when I was a beginning programmer, I had exactly this sort of problem in front of me.  I stared at it for like fifteen minutes trying to work it out and then suddenly I did, and I felt kinda dumb that it wasn't obvious to me from the start.  I think that most people go through that process.  You just asked for help rather than worked it out.  Same basic process.  Same result.

Comment: @Csharpz: If there is a day that goes by that I don't feel "kind of dumb" for at least a minute then I must have slept in... :)